# Blog featured images disappeared on my homepage

Tags: posts, images, post-thumbnails, homepage, blog

I am quite new to this but I edited and updated a website which has the blog area on the homepage. The website is a one page website and the blog area is also called 'News'. The blog was yet still created as a new page and the featured images were shown before using 'post grid' but stopped showing and now shows blue boxes from the branding of the website. The blog page also has been categorized as 'Digital Advertising'. Does anyone have an easy fix to help me get the featured images to be displayed like it used to?

Code below:
[vc_empty_space][ultimate_heading main_heading="NEWS" main_heading_color="#000000" main_heading_font_family="font_family:PT Sans|font_call:PT+Sans|variant:700" main_heading_style="font-weight:700;" main_heading_font_size="desktop:56px;"][/ultimate_heading][vc_empty_space][vc_basic_grid post_type="post" max_items="10" grid_id="vc_gid:1550684152354-9952e6d1-8e6b-5"][vc_empty_space]

Thanks

[image] 
[image: News section]

Comment: The blog page is going to use either `home.php` or  `archive.php` or something more specific down that line of the [template hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/).  If whatever template it's using doesn't output `the_content` then anything you did in a page builder won't show up there.

Comment: Thank You, makes a lot of sense now. I resorted to downloading a Post Grid plugin and the featured image and layout is fine.